# Number of tasks completed while executor is still running

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, executor

Is there any way to find the number of tasks completed after a call to invokeAll()? It seems that that  returns the list of booleans of completed tasks when all of the threads are completed.

I have a pool of 1000 tasks and want to take a look at them in 100 intervals without having to divide the them into 100-task batches.

I also for compatibility reasons have to work with Java 6 so newer methods won't help.

Also, as a side question: does the invokeAll() processes the tasks in FIFO manner? That is, are the tasks get started with the order with which they are added to the task list?

Thanks

Comment: Thank you. I have two types of tasks A and B.  I want to know when all type A and type B tasks are completed. Types A and B are structurally the same but the data that type A works with is bigger and that is why it takes longer. I thought it would be nice to define the following variables in task classes: 1) final static int NTYPEATOComplete; 2) static int nTypeATasksCompleted;3) static long timeOfComepletion_A;  and same for type B. Then, at the end of call() I add nTypeATasks++ and check if =100. If so I record the completion time.  Is it OK? also #workers=nCPU-1 as the tasks are heavy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have a pool of 1000 tasks and want to take a look at them in 100 intervals without having to divide the them into 100-task batches.

You should consider using an [`ExecutorCompletionService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html) which allows you to get notified once a single job has finished instead of having to wait for *all* jobs to complete using `invokeAll()`.  Then you can put each of the finished jobs into a collection and then act on them when you get 100.

Maybe something like:

```
CompletionService<Result> ecs = new ExecutorCompletionService<Result>(executor);
for (Callable<Result> s : solvers)
    ecs.submit(s);
int n = solvers.size();
List<Result> batch = new ArrayList<Result>();
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    Result r = ecs.take().get();
    batch.add(r);
    if (batch.size() >= 100) {
       process(batch);
       batch.clear();
    }
}
if (!batch.isEmpty()) {
    process(batch);
}
```

> does the invokeAll() processes the tasks in FIFO manner? That is, are the tasks get started with the order with which they are added to the task list?

The tasks are submitting to the thread-pool in FIFO manner and are dequeued by the threads also in FIFO order.  However, once each thread has a job, there are race conditions which may cause some re-ordering of the actual task "start" and certainly finish.

Answer (score 0):

Tasks will be added in the order you specify, and approximately started in that order if you have multiple threads.  The order they are completed will be roughly in that order if they take the same amount of time.

I would build a `List<Future>` which you can poll periodically to see how many are done.